# Session Data doesn't show up in the Next page

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I am trying to put some data into Session in PHP. I can set and print the session variables in the same page. But when i try to print the same variable in the next page by hitting the URL in the browser, it just doesn't show. Shows up NULL

Here is the code for the page used to set the Session variables.

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['id'] = '2';
$_SESSION['name'] = 'name';
$_SESSION['who'] = 'admin';

echo "ID ->".$_SESSION['id']."<br>";
echo "Name ->".$_SESSION['name']."<br>";
echo "who ->".$_SESSION['who']."<br>";
var_dump( $_SESSION );
```

This gives the following output

```
ID -> 2
Name ->name
who ->admin
array(3) { ["id"]=> &string(1) "1" ["name"]=> &string(15) "name" ["who"]=> &string(5) "admin" }
```

However the next has exactly the same code.

```
session_start();
var_dump( $_SESSION )."<br>";
echo "ID ->".$_SESSION['id']."<br>";
echo "Name ->".$_SESSION['name']."<br>";
echo "who ->".$_SESSION['who']."<br>";
```

This gives the following output.

```
array(5) { ["id"]=> &NULL ["name"]=> &NULL ["who"]=> &NULL } 
ID ->
Name ->
who ->
```

Please help.

Comment: it seems like your overwriting the values somewhere because the keys are present in your `var_dump`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As i have written the pages contain just these lines of code. Nothing else. I just found out that this is working in IE 8.